# Squeeze two results in one row

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way to join two result rows together.

I've got two tables:

**settings table:**

```
id | pop_setting1_id | pop_setting2_id
```

**user table:**

```
user_id | setting_id
```

`pop_setting1_id` and `pop_setting2_id` in first table points to `setting_id` in second table

I would like to have a query that takes one parameter (id) and gives one row result like:

```
user_id as user_id_1 | user_id as user_id_2 | setting_id as setting_id1 | setting_id as setting_id2
```

made from two rows from user table, where setting_id matches pop_setting1_id or pop_setting2_id respectively.

Setting_id in user table is unique, so it's for sure that it will be only two results. All I want is to rename those results and squeeze them in one row. Give me some hints please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this::

```
Select 

u1.user_id as user_id_1,
u2.user_id as user_id_2, 
u1.setting_id as setting_id1,
u2.setting_id as setting_id2, 
from 
`settings` s
INNER JOIN `user` u1 on (s.pop_setting1_id=u1.setting_id)
INNER JOIN `user` u2 on (s.pop_setting2_id=u2.setting_id)

WHERE id=?
```

Comment: I just modified it to LEFT JOIN, so it returns something, when there's some missing entry in user table.